# How can I write these methods in a more generic way in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have the following class hierarchy:

`EstadoBaseMO` (parent)

- `EstadoSAMO(EstadoBaseMO child)`
- `EstadoGesDocMO(EstadoBaseMO child)`

`SolicitudBasePresenter`(parent)

- `SolicitudGesDocPresenter(SolicitudBasePresenter child)`
- `SolicitudSAPresenter(SolicitudBasePresenter child)`

`EstadoBaseBO`(parent)

- `EstadoGesDocBO(EstadoBaseBO child)`
- `EstadoSABO(EstadoBaseBO child)`

I need to implement a method called `SaveNewDetailStates`, with the following implementation in `SolicitudBasePresente` is

```
public bool SaveNewDetailStates(List<EstadoBaseMO> estados)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (estados.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                EstadoGesDocBO bo = new EstadoGesDocBO();

                foreach (var estado in estados)
                {

                    var savedState = bo.Insert(estado);
                    result &= ((savedState != null) && (savedState.Id != estado.Id));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

`SolicitudGesDocPresenter.SaveNewDetailStates` implementation

```
public bool SaveNewDetailStates(List<EstadoGesDocMO> estados)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (estados.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                EstadoGesDocBO bo = new EstadoGesDocBO();

                foreach (var estado in estados)
                {

                    var savedState = bo.Insert(estado);
                    result &= ((savedState != null) && (savedState.Id != estado.Id));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

`SolicitudSAPresenter.SaveNewDetailStates` implementation

```
 public bool SaveNewDetailStates(List<EstadoSAMO> estados)
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (estados.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                EstadoSABO bo = new EstadoSABO();

                foreach (var estado in estados)
                {

                    var savedState = bo.Insert(estado);
                    result &= ((savedState != null) && (savedState.Id != estado.Id));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

As you can see, the code is exactly the same with two differences, in `SolicitudSAPresenter` I'm using `EstadoSAMO` and `EstadoSABO` classes, similar in `SolicitudGesDocPresenter`.
Things to know:

- I don't really need an implementation of `SolicitudBasePresenter.SaveNewDetailStates`
- I tried to convert the parent method(`SolicitudBasePresenter.SaveNewDetailStates`) to an abstract method, but then, the `SAPresenter` and `GesDocPresenter` can't use override because they need to implement the same signature (and it's not the same..), besides, soon after I realized I need a concrete implementation of `SolicitudBasePresenter`, so it shouldn't be an abstract class (similar happens with a virtual method)
- Maybe the use of generics can solve that problem, but I'm still not used to them. I tried with something like `SaveNewDetailStates<T,K>(List<T> estados)`, but then I'm lost and I don't know what else can I do.

What is the best approach for writing this code?

The only solution I have is to delete the `SaveNewDetailStates` from parent presenter, and write the concrete implementation in children and then everything is fine but...I don't think that's even a solution for a good developer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Generics but you still need to use Interfaces to implement what you need, but you can do it only with Interfeces similar to this, I made separate IEstadoState and IEstadoMO to make it more clear if you don't need additional fields in your logic you can make one interface instead of these two

```
public interface IEstadoState 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IEstadoMO
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IEstadoBO
{
    IEstadoState Insert(IEstadoMO estadoMO);
}

public class SolicitudBasePresenter
{
    public virtual bool SaveNewDetailStates(List<IEstadoMO> estados, IEstadoBO estadoBO) 
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (estados.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var estado in estados)
                {

                    var savedState = estadoBO.Insert(estado);
                    result &= ((savedState != null) && (savedState.Id != estado.Id));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class SolicitudGesDocPresenter : SolicitudBasePresenter { }

public class SolicitudSAPresenter : SolicitudBasePresenter { }
```

if you prefer to use Generic or don't want to pass second parameter to method here is how it will look

```
public class SolicitudBasePresenter<T1, T2> where T1 : IEstadoMO where T2 : IEstadoBO, new()
{
    public bool SaveNewDetailStates(List<T1> estados) 
    {
        bool result = true;

        if (estados.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var estado in estados)
                {
                    var estadoBO = new T2();
                    var savedState = estadoBO.Insert(estado);
                    result &= ((savedState != null) && (savedState.Id != estado.Id));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class EstadoState : IEstadoState
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class EstadoBaseMO : IEstadoMO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class EstadoBaseBO : IEstadoBO
{
    public IEstadoState Insert(IEstadoMO estado) { return new EstadoState(); }
}

public class EstadoSAMO : EstadoBaseMO { }

public class EstadoGesDocMO : EstadoBaseMO { }

public class EstadoGesDocBO : EstadoBaseBO { }

public class EstadoSABO : EstadoBaseBO { }

public class SolicitudGesDocPresenter : SolicitudBasePresenter<EstadoGesDocMO, EstadoGesDocBO> { }

public class SolicitudSAPresenter : SolicitudBasePresenter<EstadoSAMO, EstadoSABO> { }
```

your method call will be

```
    var docPresenter = new SolicitudGesDocPresenter();
    docPresenter.SaveNewDetailStates(new List<EstadoGesDocMO>());
```

also you can declare children like this

```
public class SolicitudGesDocPresenter<T1, T2> : SolicitudBasePresenter<T1, T2> where T1 : IEstadoMO where T2 : IEstadoBO, new() { }

public class SolicitudSAPresenter<T1, T2> : SolicitudBasePresenter<T1, T2> where T1 : IEstadoMO where T2 : IEstadoBO, new() { }
```

you'll call it in this way

```
    var docPresenter = new SolicitudGesDocPresenter<EstadoGesDocMO, EstadoGesDocBO>();
    docPresenter.SaveNewDetailStates(new List<EstadoGesDocMO>());
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use Generics. Define the class `EstadoBaseMO<T>` and then use the type `T` in your save method.

```
public bool SaveNewDetailStates(List<T> estados)
```

Your child classes can then (for example) extend `EstadoBaseMO<SolicitudBasePresenter>`.

There are lots of generics tutorials online, have a look at some of them.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx